# Join of 3 Tables - How to walk through results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql statement joining 3 tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `int_news` 
                       LEFT JOIN tl_member ON int_news.member_id = tl_member.id
                       LEFT JOIN tl_news ON int_news.news_id = tl_news.id
```

The 3 Tables are like this:

Table 1 (int_news)
ID, member_id, news_id

Table 2 (tl_member)
id, firstname, lastname

Table 3 (tl_news)
id, headline

So far so good, but it seems i have a big blackhole in my head making me unable to solve how to output the result like this

For each "headline" i want ALL lastnames e.g.

```
headline 1       Jonny
                 Walker
                 Jim

headline 2       Knopf
                 Jon
                 Doe
```

Comment: The general algorithm is pretty simple.  On start of your loop, write the headline and save it in a variable. Continue looping and writing out names. On each loop, check the value of the headline - if it is the same as your variable, don't write it out. If the headline doesn't match your variable, write the new headline and store it in your variable. Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds your looking something like a pivot so if you group your query by headline, it will display each lastname as a column.

I found this good tutorial on pivots for mysql that might help you http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

```
headline 1       Jonny    Walker    Jim

headline 2       Knopf    Jon       Doe
```

Here is a loop that would do that *Forgive my php it's been a while.

```
$curHeadline = "";

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    if($curHeadline != $db_field['headline'])
    {
        $curHeadline = $db_field['headline'];
        print $curHeadline . $db_field['ID']
    }

    print $db_field['lastName'] . "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: Not a pivot, but rather just only writing out the headline once each time it changes.

Comment: That would something better handled in code, in my opinion.   As records are being displayed in the loop check if the new headline matches the old one.

Comment: that's what I'm implying. This is a question of formatting, not querying.

Comment: Thanks this was the thing i had in mind, but sometimes the obvious is not willing to come. The storing of the headline in a variable was  the breaking point for me

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this vaguely reflect your situation?

```
<?php

$sql = "
    SELECT
        `int_news`.`ID` AS `int_news_ID`, 
        `int_news`.`member_id`, 
        `int_news`.`news_id`, 
        `t1_member`.`id` AS `t1_member_id`, 
        `t1_member`.`firstname`,
        `t1_member`.`lastname`,      /* desired */
        `t1_news`.`id` AS `t1_news_id`, 
        `t1_news`.`headline`         /* desired */
    FROM
        `int_news` 
    LEFT JOIN `tl_member` ON `int_news`.`member_id` = `tl_member`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `tl_news` ON `int_news`.`news_id` = `tl_news`.`id`
";

$res = mysql_query($query);

$arrHeadings = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
 // We want to output the results in groups of headings
 $arrHeadings[$row['heading']][] = $row;
}

// Don't forget to cleanse for html output (unlike below)
// Loop through the headers
foreach($arrHeadings as $heading=>$arrRow) {
 echo '<dl>';
 echo '<dt>'.$heading.'</dt>';
 echo '<dd>';

 // Loop through rows with the same header
 foreach($arrRow as $index=>$dbRow) {
  echo $dbRow['lastname'].'<br />';
 }

 echo '</dd>';
 echo '</dl>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Yikes! I would advise against writing your SQL in concatenated strings like this - it makes it difficult to maintain. You can split PHP strings over many lines - just put `$sql = "` at the start and `";` at the end. You can even indent your SQL, and the database engine won't mind at all.

Comment: @halfer yeah! But in this case he should use `HEREDOC`. And also, DO NOT PRINT HTML TAGS!!!! Use alternate control structures instead

Comment: @MyStream: I am not sure I see why it would wrap awkwardly in the editor if you put in newlines in sensible places. As I said in my comment, a single SQL string can be formatted over many lines.

Comment: @metal_fan - it's a matter of taste, I suppose. I personally don't like HEREDOC as the delimiter cannot be preceded with whitespace, and so the indentation is spoilt.

Comment: @MyStream - yes indeed, the Stack Overflow editor. See my edit for what I meant. (Aside: I find the backticks superfluous as well, so would tend to suggest they're only used where a reserved word is used for a column. But I've left them in here).

Comment: @MyStream done, and thanks - added the missing line. That was an oversight :)

Comment: I wonder if that goes above > -1 now... thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this for mysql :

```
SELECT tlnews.headline, GROUP_CONCAT(tl_member.last_name)
FROM `int_news`  LEFT JOIN tl_member ON int_news.member_id = tl_member.id
                 LEFT JOIN tl_news   ON int_news.news_id   = tl_news.id
GROUP BY 1;

Expected Output:

headline1  Johnny,Walker,Jim
headline2  Knopf,Jon,Doe
...
```